# Missing some data stored through object caching in memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, objectcache

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3.I've cached some data using object caching in memory.In some cases,it opted out some caching data.
for example.

I've stored array of integer number;

int[] i;

i[0]=0;

i[1]=1;

i[2]=2;

i[3]=3;

i[4]=4;

i[5]=5;

and cached array i;

In some cases,
when i retrieve array,it will display only 3 elements.it will opted out first 2 elements and after that i never get those first 2 elements until i restart application from IIS or remove it from caching using remove method.

I cant figure it out what is wrong.
What could be the reason?

Comment: So you are storing the array, then retrieving the array and when you retrieve it, it has changed?

Comment: Yes.when i retrieve ,  get only 3 elements.

Comment: So there must be code that changes the array somewhere -- code that takes elements out or that replaces the array by another.

Comment: is there any other possibility rather than this?

Comment: Try this: as soon as you put the array in the cache, see if you can read it back (immediately). If you get it back correctly, then there must be code *somewhere* that modifies the array.